# Code to find count in list generates error

Tags: python, count

I have a script to find the count of some word in a list

```
newm =[]
for i in range(0,len(alpha)-1):
    newm.append (alpha[i][0])
print newm
#count for list
word_counter =[]
for word in newm:
  print word
  if word in word_counter:
      word_counter[word] += 1
  else:
      word_counter[word] = 1
```

`newm` generates:

```
['today', 'alpha', 'radiation', 'helium', 'work', 'charge', 'model', 'atom', 'discovery', 'interpretation', 'scattering', 'gold', 'foil', 'splitting', 'atom', 'reaction', 'nitrogen', 'alpha']
```

I want to find the count of each word in the list newm however it gives the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: And `newm` can be defined as : `newm = [item[0] for item in alpha]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution using `defaultdict`.

```
In [23]: from collections import defaultdict
In [24]: data = ['a','b','c','a','b','b','d']
In [25]: counts = defaultdict(int)
In [26]: for x in data: counts[x]+=1
In [27]: counts
Out[27]: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a dictionary:

```
word_counter = {}

if word in word_counter:
    word_counter[word] += 1
else:
    word_counter[word] = 1
```

The `if/else` is used to check if the dictionary already contains the word. If it does, it will increment its associated value, if it doesn't, it initializes the value to 1.

[Python dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

And, to find out more about why your code wasn't working, here's [more on lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

As mentioned by [Ashwini Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846892/ashwini-chaudhary) you can also use `collections.Counter` whose purpose is to do this kind of thing:

```
>>> # Tally occurrences of words in a list
>>> cnt = Counter()
>>> for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
...     cnt[word] += 1
>>> cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

and here's an example of how to initalize it directly from an iterable:

```
>>> c = Counter(['eggs','ham'])
>>> c
Counter({'eggs': 1, 'ham': 1})
>>> c['bacon']
0
>>> c['ham']
1
```

Examples taken from: [collections: Counter Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

Comment: or better use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: You don't even need the loop; `Counter(newm)` would have sufficed.